# Is it possible to render a template from middleware?

Tags: django, django-templates, render, middleware

I have a middleware that does some processing. On certain conditions it raises an exception and the user sees my `500.html` template - correctly responding to 500 http status.

Now, on some exceptions I would like to render different template than default `500.html`. Is it possible/how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch those exceptions and [return a HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to render your custom template. Or maybe a redirect is also appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... and no.

You can render whatever you want (your web server has a nice explanation how to do that), but whether the user will see that is his choice - through his browser settings. It is possible you render something, but the browser still shows a standard error page.

Answer (score 0):

A middleware might be a solution:

```
class MyExceptionMiddleware:
   def process_exception(self, request, exception):

     if isinstance(exception, CustomException):
       template = loader.get_template('Other500.html')
       context = RequestContext(request, {'message': 'Custom Message'})
       return HttpResponseForbidden(template.render(context))

     return None
```

Don't forget to register the middleware in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ....
    'app.middleware.MyExceptionMiddleware',
```